# Is there a way to collapse weighted means in R?

Tags: r, grouping, stata, mean, weighted

I am trying to translate the following code from Stata to R:

```
collapse (mean) erate_total_male laborforce_male erate_total_male_1953 laborforce_male_1953 share_expellees_male share_dest_flats instrument share_agric_1939 city_state (max) occzone_occu [aw=laborforce_male], by(bundesland_id_1953 occupation_id)
```

I have attempted to use the `collapse` package in R, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the weight element of the Stata code or the maximum value (though I may just generate a new variable to work around that).

```
test1 <- rep_data %>%
  mutate(bundesland_id_1953 = 
           case_when(
             bundesland_id == 8 ~ 99,
             bundesland_id == 9 ~ 99,
             bundesland_id == 10 ~ 99,
           )) %>%
  group_by(bundesland_id_1953, occupation_id) %>% 
  select(erate_total_male, laborforce_male, erate_total_male_1953, laborforce_male_1953, share_expellees_male, share_dest_flats, instrument_male, share_agric_1939, city_state, occzone_occu) %>% fmean
```

I have also attempted to generate means for all of the variables, but I run into the same issue with adding the weight:

```
t6Data2 <- rep_data %>%
  mutate(bundesland_id_1953 = 
           case_when(
             bundesland_id == 8 ~ 99,
             bundesland_id == 9 ~ 99,
             bundesland_id == 10 ~ 99,
           )) %>% 
  group_by(bundesland_id_1953, occupation_id) %>% summarise_at(vars(erate_total_male, laborforce_male, erate_total_male_1953, laborforce_male_1953, share_expellees_male, share_dest_flats, instrument_male, share_agric_1939, city_state)
```

Finally, I attempted a loop, but my variables do not appear when I run a regression using lm():

```
test444 <- rep_data %>%
  mutate(bundesland_id_1953 = 
           case_when(
             bundesland_id == 8 ~ 99,
             bundesland_id == 9 ~ 99,
             bundesland_id == 10 ~ 99,
           )) %>% 
  group_by(bundesland_id_1953, occupation_id)

t6_data_test4 <- sapply(c(test444$erate_total_male, test444$laborforce_male, test444$erate_total_male_1953, test444$laborforce_male_1953, test444$share_expellees_male, test444$share_dest_flats, test444$instrument_male, test444$share_agric_1939, test444$city_state), function(x) {
  weighted.mean(x, weight = laborforce_male)
})
```

I am not sure what to do, but I would appreciate any help. I am a relative novice, so I apologize for any obvious errors I've made in my code.

Comment: It is easier to help if you share data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I am a Stata person and can see that you are aiming at R people who also know Stata very well. You are much more likely to get detailed responses if you show a very small example dataset with a few rows (observations) and columns (variables) and explain directly what analytic weights imply when calculating a mean. That is the `[aw=...]` syntax. In fact the Stata syntax is arguably irrelevant here. You could just ask directly how to do what you want in R.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```r
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble::tibble(
  bundesland_id_1953 = sample(letters[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE),
  occupation_id = factor(sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)),
  x = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE),
  weight = runif(100)
)

d <- group_by(d, bundesland_id_1953, occupation_id)

bind_cols(
  group_keys(d),
  group_split(d) %>% 
    purrr::map_df(
      # [NOTE] use `across` in forthcoming dplyr 1.0.0
      ~ summarise_at(.x, vars(x, y), weighted.mean, w = .x$weight)
    )
)
```

I'm not happy with the solution below because it's uglier than what 'tidy' tools are meant to provide. Damn, it's less legible than Stata -- I'm disappointed with myself.

I'm also suspicious of your weighting scheme: at some point, it looks like you're weighting a variable by… itself? But I don't know the data, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a faithful translation of your STATA code in R is:

```
library(collapse)
collap(data, by = ~ bundesland_id_1953 + occupation_id, 
       custom = list(fmean = .c(rate_total_male, laborforce_male, erate_total_male_1953, laborforce_male_1953, 
                                share_expellees_male, share_dest_flats instrument share_agric_1939, city_state), 
                     fmax_uw = "occzone_occu"), w = ~ laborforce_male)
```

Note the `_uw` postfix is used for `fmax` as per documentation `?collap` to avoid an unused argument warning caused by that weight vector passed to `fmax` (which cannot handle weights). Note also that the `collap` default is `keep.w = TRUE` with `wFUN = fsum`, so your weight vector `"laborforce_male"` will be aggregated as well using the sum. Another collapse option you have, using more dplyr-like code is (Let `...` be the variables inside `.c` in the code above, entered without quotes):

```
library(magrittr)
data %>% fgroup_by(bundesland_id_1953, occupation_id) %>% 
   collapg(custom = list(fmean = .c(...), fmax_uw = "occzone_occu"), 
           w = laborforce_male)
```

Finally, if you are into programming with pipes you can also construct this from scratch using:

```
data %>% fgroup_by(bundesland_id_1953, occupation_id) %>% {
     add_vars(fselect(., ...) %>% fmean(laborforce_male), 
              fselect(., occzone_occu) %>% fmax(keep.group_vars = FALSE)) 
}
```

If you are only aggregating with the weighted mean the latter expression can become a lot simpler:

```
data %>% fgroup_by(bundesland_id_1953, occupation_id) %>% 
     fselect(...) %>% fmean(laborforce_male)
```

Let me know where you had difficulties understanding the documentation of `collap`.